# How do I make my kid’s Android phone ring even if silenced when I call him?

Tags: audio, calls, silent-mode, parental-control

Sometimes my kids forget to put their phones on ring mode and then I can’t reach them. I’m looking for a solution that will unmute their Galaxy S7 when my or my wife call them.

Comment: you can send a voice note - 99% sure they will hear it within a minute ;)

Comment: especially when parents call their kids :D but they can not resist to click on play on any stupid voice note

Comment: "voice note"? I've never heard this term.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths lol i don't use WhatsApp but i am sure you know what i mean. It is that nice feature when they push the microphone button, speak, send a 00:02 / 2 MB *.opus file and bleed out their monthly data volume instead of typing "yes" in a sms text message

Answer (score 1):

It might not be applicable if your kids are older, but my kid just got his first phone and I manage it with [Google Family Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.kids.familylink&hl=en). Even when the phone is on silent I can make it play a sound and get him to answer a call or message. It's worked out really well for me, the one thing I don't know is if you can have more than one family device managers to manage the family's devices. It might be worth checking out at least.

I can also use it for managing screen time restrictions and other parental controls that I really felt were missing in cheap, stock Android phones.

Comment: I have Google family link and I see nowhere on the app where I can make his phone ring and on top of it now hes not listed under find my device (a separate Google app) now that I'm supervising his and so now we have no way to make his phone go iff so we can find the dang thing every time he loses it ..